# does grep regex work differently on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, regex, grep

Just trying to figure out basic use of regexes with grep (or egrep) in mac terminal (BSD grep - 2.5.1-FreeBSD).

File to examine (`pow.txt`) contains the lines :

```
kiytytytyty
```

and

```
blob.mkv
```

command used is :

```
grep -E ^[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}$i pow.txt
```

match returned is:

```
kiytytytyty
```

Obviously this wouldn't match with a PCRE regex. Are regexes interpreted differently on mac ? Or is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: @dsstorefile Hi. I see, the regex has to be set between quotation marks. AND the dot had to be escaped, AND case insensitive flag has to be placed as part of command params. :) Thanks ! I guess this closes the topic.

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to quote it; you could also escape all of the characters that have special meaning to the shell. But there's a bunch of them and it's easy to get the escaping wrong; single-quotes are simpler. BTW, instead of "`\.`", you could use "`[.]`" to match a period character, and you could use `[a-zA-Z]` for the character classes instead of the `-i` option to `grep`. There's lots of ways to do it!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Obviously this wouldn't match with a PCRE regex"   By the way there is -P  instead of -E.  -E is ERE, (which is better than BRE), but -P is more even than ERE. It's Perl Compatible Regular Expression, i.e.(I suppose!)  PCRE. Also, the fact that dot would match any character.. and [.] would match a literal dot. is not a PCRE specific thing.

Comment: @barlop yes totally right about the dot, where the problem came from. I thought the problem was differences between ERE and PCRE. BTW, -P doesn't seem to work on my command (=> usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ]), do you have to install it ?

Comment: @Rmy5 ah maybe -P isn't on Mac!   (unless perhaps you can get GNU grep on your mac).  It enables for example positive lookahead like `(?=abc)`   `-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression`  (dunno if -P is PCRE or Perl regex) but seems to be a GNU thing.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx     after installing it you should be able to run it as `ggrep` apparently

Comment: if you happen to use `silverarrow` you can grep for file names with `ag -g '^[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}$'`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're trying to match `blob.mkv`, try:

```
grep -Ei '^[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}$' pow.txt
```

Comment: And no; regex is not interpreted differently on the Mac. But your shell ate the backslash (and probably replaced `$i` with an empty string unless you have something in this variable) because you didn't quote the regex.

Comment: Having said that, PCRE syntax is different from the regex dialect supported by `grep -E` on every platform, not just on the Mac. GNU `grep` has `grep -P` for PCRE syntax; it used to exist on the Mac, too, but was dropped for reasons only Apple can explain. Perhaps read up on BRE vs ERE vs PCRE. Briefly, `\s \w \d` and friends, lookarounds, named groups, atomic matching, and non-greedy quantifiers are some of the features only present in PCRE.